# Change navbar collapse width Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to workout how to modify the collapse width of the navbar within Bootstrap 3 so that it will collapse at an earlier width. I have found several suggestions but none seem to work. The closest I got was the code from this post [Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar-collapse - set width to collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703550/twitter-bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse-set-width-to-collapse?answertab=active#tab-top)

Here's what that post used:

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

}

This causes the collapse to happen when I want it however, it breaks the collapse at the same time. The collapse button appears when it's supposed to however when I click on it the menu appears for just a second and then automatically closes. Is there a way to stop the auto close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very easy way do do this,

1. [Click here to customize Bootstraps LESS variables](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables#)
2. Change `@grid-float-breakpoint` to the size of your choice
3. Click **compile and download**
4. Use the resulting CSS on your page!

Comment: I've tried using the @grid-float-breakpoint and that doesn't seem to work either. I set it to 1080px, compiled and downloaded it, copied that CSS file over my existing and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 3.1, the navbar changed slightly from 3.0, so there are some changes to the CSS you'd use to override the breakpoint..

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
       float: none!important;
   margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/120604

---

**Related**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289507/171456